# Xcode 10.2.1 Riot-iOS Project not building on real device iPhone 7

Tags: iphone, ios12, xcode10.2.1, element-io

When I build a application on real device its showing error. While I run on simulator its working fine.

> :-1: unexpected service error: build aborted due to an internal error:
>   unable to write manifest to
>   '/Users/premkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Riot-fnfjowwnlogoplabpdycfbxnfphu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/bc7aae4cefeb8078053bdd3a99d3fcca-manifest.xcbuild':
>   fwrite(): No space left on device (28)

I was quit Xcode and reopened and tested and also created and set custom location for derived Data.

Still its not happening.

Comment: In this error, it is saying "No space left on device (28)". Did you check storage space of your device?

Comment: Ya, my iPhone is having 3.95GB free space

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue with 13.55 GB of available space.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and while I had plenty of space left on physical device (iPad 8 in my case), I didn't have much disk space available on my Mac.

After clearing my Mac storage, everything started working fine. Which is odd that it was working on a simulator but that did the trick for me.